# Rails console with special initial commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, console, routes

I'm using Rails `script/console` to learn REST routes. It is very handful!

In order to do that I need to paste these two lines `every time` I run console:

```
include ActionController::UrlWriter
default_url_options[:host] = 'whatever'
```

If there is any way to make a script which will add this automatically every time I run console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a hack but you could put two calls in a `.rb` file and `require` that when you start the console.

E.g.

```
i.rb
  include ActionController::UrlWriter
  default_url_options[:host] = 'whatever'

$ ruby script/console
>> require 'i'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ActionController::Integration::Session object that is available at the console with the name “**app**”:

```
>> app.blog_path
=> "/blog"
```

One thing to note is that the app object's host name is automatically prepopulated to “www.example.com”:

```
>> app.host
=> "www.example.com"
>> app.blog_url
=> "http://www.example.com/blog"
```